# Showing segue after button action

Tags: swift, ios

I have an iOS Swift app with 8 buttons that call the same segue, but this is very repetitive. How can I refactor so it uses the same function `prepare`?

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.back.rawValue
    self.postion = "back"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func mountButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.mount.rawValue
    self.postion = "mount"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func kneeRideButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.knee.rawValue
    self.postion = "knee"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}


@IBAction func sideKbuttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.sideK.rawValue
    self.postion = "side"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}


@IBAction func northSouthBpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.northSouth.rawValue
    self.postion = "north"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func guardBpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.guarda.rawValue
    self.postion = "guard"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func halfGuardBpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.halfGuard.rawValue
    self.postion = "half"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func turtleBpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.vcWithType = VCtype.turtle.rawValue
    self.postion = "turtle"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCategory", sender: sender)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "showCategory") {

        if let vc: CategoryViewController = segue.destination as? CategoryViewController {
            vc.vcWithType = self.vcWithType
            vc.chaza = self.postion

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Create enum of your position, and instead of calling independent method on every button, call only one method.

Answer (score 3):

I think easiest way is using `tag`s.
You can connect more then one button to one `IBAction func`. Just Make sure sender is UIButton.

[image]

After that change buttons tag property.

[image]

After changing tags. We just need to use `switch-case`

```
@IBAction func ButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      switch sender.tag {
            case 0:
                print("Button 1 Clicked")
            case 1:
                print("Button 2 Clicked")
            default: break
      }
}
```

Comment: You can set the tag programmatically if you don't want to dig around in Interface Builder setting them. To reduce the chance of typos, you might want to use an `enum` to store your tags and reference the enum when setting the button tags.